# How to POST data to MySQL using Jquery AJAX in .NET webforms

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, ajax

I am currently working on my website in VS2013 using ASP.NET C#. 
I have a working voting method on my site, that is, the votes get saved in the database, you can vote up or down. 
The problem is, the result of your vote doesn't show since everything is happening on the server side. 
I can't find any information on how to use JS/Ajax to post data to a MySQL database. 
Can anyone direct me to a tutorial or help me out?

HTML:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="BtnUp" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WebsiteID").ToString() %>' OnCommand="up_click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The method this button calls (C#):

```
public void click(int webID, int vote)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Website] SET [Rating]+=@vote WHERE [WebsiteID]=@webID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@webID", webID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vote", vote);

                    con.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void up_click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            String webID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(webID);
            click(ID, 1);
        }
```

As you can see, the information is saved to the database, so maybe even a GET command could solve my problem somehow. I am fairly green to Ajax, trying to learn but I really need help with how to post to a database. What to I put in "url:"? what do I put in "data:"?

ex:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'savevote', //What url to use for mySQL database?
                data: { itemId: itemId, voteType: voteType }, //how do i post the data?
                type: 'POST',
                success: votePostSuccess,
                error: votePostError
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What url to use for mySQL database?

Depends what you have, if it just webforms then a url with `aspx`. It would be nice if you have a webservice.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'yourservice.asmx/Savevote',
   data: { itemId: itemId, voteType: voteType }, 
   type: 'POST',
   success: votePostSuccess,
   error: votePostError
});
```

> how do i post the data?

You get the values from your controls using jquery, nothing different

```
[WebMethod]
public string Savevote(string itemId, string voteType)
{
   //put ADO.net here
   return success ? votePostSuccess : votePostError;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works without using ADO.net?

Comment: you would use ado.net to insert, the same code you have there

Comment: I found a tutorial but its visual basic http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/jquery/how-do-i-make-ajax-calls-using-jquery im going to look for a C# one @iQue

Comment: Ill watch the vid tomorrow, at least the logic will be there